# No tests found on running jest with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, gruntjs, jestjs

I am trying to run my jest with a grunt task but on doing so I get No tests found message in console. Here is the setup for the same:

**gruntfile.js snippet :**

```
exec: {
        jest: 'node node_modules/jest/bin/jest -u --config="test/unit/jest/jest.conf.json"'
}
```

**jest.conf.json :**

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./enzyme.setup.js",
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-teamcity-reporter"
}
```

**enzyme.setup.js :**

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15.4';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Console on running the grunt exec task shows below:

```
No tests found
In C:\Vishal\UI\Jest-Grunt\proj\test\unit\jest
  3 files checked.
  testMatch: .js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 3 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches

Done, without errors.
```

However the surprising thing is if I don't pass the jest config file path in cli inside grunt exec task and instead specify the jest configuration in package.json file then it works.

Not sure why this is behaving like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aah, after banging my head around. I noticed that the error is pity straight forward:

***In C:\My-User\UI\Jest-Grunt\proj\test\unit\jest***

This clearly explains that JEST tries to execute test cases inside folder specified above. But ideally JEST looks into `__tests__`. Hence I had to specify the roots folder myself. With package json this doesn't occur. Strange though!

Here is my updates jest configuration:

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./enzyme.setup.js",
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-teamcity-reporter",
    "coverageReporters": [
        "teamcity", "lcov"
   ],
    "roots": [
      "../../../__tests__"
    ]
}
```